# Excel 2016 Ctrl+' in foreign keyboards

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I intend to *exactly* copy a cell formula for an entire column.

Unfortunately, Excel always increases the referenced cell id, so I searched for a solution.

I learned that the key combination of Ctrl+' (apostrophe) can do it, but I can't find it on my non-English keyboard. If I press the apostrophe combination (Shift+1) with Ctrl, it opens the cell customization.

So how can I use that command without a dedicated **'** key? Is there a button for it?

Comment: Why not add `$` in front of the row/column you wish to remain unchanged in your formula?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad It is a good idea but the question still remains as there are other important key combinations yet I'm not sure whether they can work with a foreign keyboard.

Comment: Using 4 different language keyboards I am well aware of the problem and have never found a universal fix. The best we can do is work around it :(